# Keep the focus in the current section when resizing the window

Tags: html, css

I have a page with several sections that occupy the entire height and width of the screen, the idea is that the user only see one section at a time, but when resizing the window it reveals part of the previous or next section:

```css
html, body{
  overflow:hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#one{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#two{
  background-color: blue;
}

#three{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
  <section id="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="#three">Three</a>
  </section>
  <section id="two">
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <h1>Two</h1>
    <a href="#three">Three</a>
  </section>
  <section id="three">
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I avoid seeing part of a different section when the window is resized? I want to always keep the focus on the section I'm currently in (if I'm in two and resize do not see a part of one)

Comment: I can't see the problem you're describing

Comment: @Aaron3219 resize the window vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Ah! Click on the sections "two" or "three" and resize vertically to reproduce.

Comment: I don't know if this can be achieved only with CSS, would you consider using JavaScript?